# multiple insert queries and passing variables in-between. mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do 3 simultaneous inserts into 3 tables as the user registers to my site.
Here are my tables:

UPDATED ANSWER. simplified the question:

## Table 1

```
 ControlPanelID
 UserDescription
 ChannelCommentsID  
 UserID
```

## Table 2

```
UserID
UserName
Password
Email
Reputation
ControlPanelID
Role
```

Here are my 3 insert Statements:

```
$queryString=
            "INSERT INTO ControlPanel VALUES("",ChannelCommentsID , userID)".
            "INSERT INTO users VALUES($userNam,$pass,$email, ,'anonym')";
```

I want the UserID row to increment in both tables..how is that being acheived?

in other words opening the connection to the database twice... (i.e. 2 queries)?

Comment: your schema is not third normal form ER! :S

Comment: basically this is what i want.. A user fills a form, ... his name and details are being created, then the UserID goes by 1. But I want the UserID to go up by 1 in the ControlPanel as well. How do do that?!?

Comment: What I mean is that you can not have two tables with this property! is not a well-designed database and then I think it's impossible to do what you want!

Comment: Of course it's not impossible. Just unnecessarily difficult. You return the ID and then use that to insert into the second table. You remove the auto-increment ID from the second table. It'd be easier and more obvious what's going on if the DB was in 3NF+.

Comment: nice point JellyBelly. I solved the problem..I deleted a few fields i didnt need to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the value of the AUTOINCREMENT column for the previous INSERT.

In your specific case, this may be a possible solution

```
$queryString=
    "INSERT INTO users VALUES($userNam,$pass,$email, ,'anomy')".
    "INSERT INTO ControlPanel VALUES("",ChannelCommentsID , LAST_INSERT_ID())";
```

Comment: I think that that statement would suffice.. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The UserID field in table 2 should have the attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT`, this will handle increasing the number automatically each time a new record is inserted.

Comment: Sorry I had to review my table design..I corrected it now to work!!1